# Anchor links to start below the header which is fixed at the top

Tags: html, css

I have a page which has a fixed header at the top, which is 63px in height.
below this I have different sections of the page (divs) which are in essence separate pages.
Each section is linked in the header as an anchor link to the relevant div id.
The problem I am having is that when the anchor link is clicked the top of the div starts right at the top of the document, rather than underneath the header. 
Any solution would be very helpful indeed.

CSS CODE FOR THE HEADER:

> ```
> #headercontainer{
> position:fixed;
> background-color:#1a1813; 
> top:0px;
> left:0px;
> width:100%;
> height:63px;
> z-index:1;}
> ```

```
#headercontent{
position:relative;
background-image:no-repeat; 
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:1280px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}
```

CSS CODE FOR THE FIRST SECTION (THAT SHOULD BE BELOW THE HEADER WHEN THE ANCHOR IS CLICKED:

```
#landingcontainer{
margin-top:63px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:700px;
background-color:#000000;}

#landingcontent{
position:relative;
width:1280px;
height:700px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-image:url("../images/landing/landing_bg.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

}

HTML UP TO POINT NEEDED:

```
<!-- START BODY CONTAINER -->
<div id="bodycontainer">
    <!-- START HEADER -->
    <div id="headercontainer">
        <!-- START HEADER CONTENT -->
        <div id="headercontent">
            <div id="headerbg">
                <a href="#landingcontainer"><div id="headerlogo"></div></a>
                <div id="headercard"></div>
                <div id="headernavigation">
                    <ul>
                        <a href="#menucontainer"><li>Menu</li></a>
                        <li>Sauces</li>
                        <li>Ranches</li>
                        <li>Order</li>
                        <li>Franchise</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="headersociallinks"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->

    <!-- START LANDING SECTION -->
    <div id="landingcontainer">
```

Comment: `margin-top: 63px` on `landingcontainer` should work. Have you tried making that `padding-top: 63px`? If that does not work I suspect you have some invalid HTML somewhere.

Comment: ive tried padding and margin. They both work when the page is loaded. the section below the header starts where it should start which is fine, however the problem is when the anchor link is clicked, the section pushes right to the top of the document. i.e 63px of the top is missing.

Comment: While there are better ways to accomplish the thing I think you're trying to accomplish, your test code worked as you said it should. I don't see any issues. Do you have any more code that may be affecting the outcome?

Comment: [This is a link to the actual files I have if someone wants a play around](http://www.mediafire.com/?k664xngu3znn7ze)

Comment: Is there no way of doing this with Jquery offset?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ive got an even better solution to this problem.

• Firstly in the css a class can be created (call it whatever you want)

```
.anchor{
   display:block;
   height:63px; /* this is the height of your header */
   margin-top:-63px; /* this is again negative value of the height of your header */
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

• In the HTML just before your actual div section starts, for example mine is `#landingcontainer` you should add a span tag with the class of anchor (which we made above) and an id of whatever you want. for me I did this :

```
<span class="anchor" id="landing"></span>
```

Then the actual link will not now be linked to your actual div id of the section you want to take them to, but rather the id of the span tag must be given in the link.

```
<a href="#landing">HOME</a>
```

AND THERE YOU HAVE IT!

what we are doing here in essence is making the browser stop where the span starts which is exactly the height of the header, which then makes the viewer non the wiser ;)

Comment: this is a great one! doesn't leave any unnecessary spacing between sections. just awesome! thanks

Comment: I love this suggestion, but instead of a span tag, i used `<a name="landing" class="anchor"></a>` put it directly above what i needed anchored, instead.  It works beautifully with your css. thanks!

Comment: Works even better if you do margin-top:-63px; padding-top:63px; Then the height of the thing you are anchoring to doesnt have to change.

Comment: Worked very well.

Comment: And you can take it even futher by using [a `::before` pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62693578/157247) -- no special markup required! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `padding-top: 63px;` to the element you're anchor linking to.  ie a hypothetical `<div id="sauceslanding">` would have CSS of `#sauceslanding { padding-top: 63px; }` with a link to it of `<a href="#sauceslanding">Sauces</a>`.

Tested it, and this works for me.  If it doesn't work for you, create a jsfiddle or some live test we can play around with to see if you may have a problem in your code somewhere.

**UPDATE**

Where you have this:

```
#menucontainer{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    background-color:#1d0f00;
    padding-top:63px;
}
/* END MENU CONTAINER */

/* MENU CONTENT */
#menucontent{
    position:relative;
    width:1280px;
    height:700px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url("../images/menu/menu_bg.png");
    background-size:cover; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Update it to this:

```
#menucontainer{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    background-color:#1d0f00;
    padding-top:63px;
    background-image:url("../images/menu/menu_bg.png");
}
/* END MENU CONTAINER */

/* MENU CONTENT */
#menucontent{
    position:relative;
    width:1280px;
    height:700px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-size:cover; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

What you'll likely see then is that the top part of the image then gets cut off as if there were no padding.  What you'll need to do then is modify your background image to have an additional 63px of dead space (extend the fence pattern North).  Then you're good to go.

Comment: okay im getting somewhere, what ive noticed is that adding a padding is fine, when the anchor is clicked it is placed in the correct place. However now there is a space of 63px on the section which is just the background color, and the background image is not present in that area of the div

Comment: Is your background image 700px tall?  The background image should extend through the padded area.  Is the padding applied to the same element as the background image is being applied to?  Do you also have a `top-margin` applied?

Comment: the code is exactly as I have it above. The background image is exactly 800px tall, not 700px which is the height of the div.

Comment: Your problem is that the background is being applied to `#menucontent` but the padding is applied to its containing `#menucontainer`.  To fix your problem, have the padding and background image applied to the same element, if possible.  Good looking site, btw.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im still having no luck applying the padding to the div that has the background image. The anchor link goes below the header with this method. However the padding issue is fine.

Comment: Can you instead apply the background image to the `#menucontainer`, instead of trying to apply padding to the `#menucontent`?

Comment: @MuhammedBhikha I've added an update to my original answer.  I think it will address the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a pageful of `<p class="paragraph" id="#uniqueid">` tags and so there's no preset/predictable height on the elements. The solution that worked best--without wreaking havoc on the rest of the established CSS/layout--was this one from [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/):

```
div#container p.paragraph:before {
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -180px; 
  height: 180px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Nothing else needed.

(FYI to anyone who is thinking of using this solution: it works as long as you don't need anything in the affected element to be clickable/selectable as this method appears to mess with actual on-screen position of things. But fine for casual browsing.)

Comment: This actually worked for me but only after I added `display:block;` as well

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Muhammed Bhikha's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037793/157247), you can avoid extra markup entirely by applying it to the `::before` element of whatever elements you want to use as anchor targets. For instance, this version uses a `::before` pseudo-element on all elements with an `id` and all `a` elements with a `name` (e.g., the usual targets). (You may want to narrow that down with a class, depending on whether you're using `::before` for something else on [say] some elements with `id`s.)

```css
a[name]::before,
[id]::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 63px;      /* this is the height of your header */
    margin-top: -63px; /* this is the height of your header, negated */
}
```

Example:

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 63px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 63px;
    background-color: blue;
}

main {
    margin-top: 63px;
}

a[name]::before,
[id]::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 63px;      /* this is the height of your header */
    margin-top: -63px; /* this is the height of your header, negated */
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header
</header>
<main>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="one">One: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p><a name="two"></a>Two: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p id="three">Three: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p><a name="four"></a>Four: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p id="five">Five: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<!-- So there's room to scroll at the bottom -->
<div style="min-height: 100vh"></div>
</main>
```