# fixed position menu on top and elements below on anchor links

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a design where my header-menu is set to fixed position, and in the menu there are anchor links to the same page. When the user clicks on this anchor link, the page scrolls down, but the top part is hidden with the menu.

How can I offset the content div that it is always below the menu?

I succesfully did it via LocalScroll js, but it seems to work only on links, and not the dropdown menu, which is shown on smaller screen width (mobile version):

```
jQuery( '#top, #wrapper' ).localScroll({offset: -150});
```

The adress is: http://www.conversionflow.nl/
(please check with smartphone, or window width < 750px - so that the dropdown menu is shown)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Pls add your code and if possible a fiddle( http://jsfiddle.net ) will be good

Comment: The answer to this other question might help: [Anchor links to start below the header which is fixed at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037793/1201863)

Answer (score 1):

```
html{
    scroll-padding-top: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the menu has a height of 75px and the content div has a css id of #content, try the following in your css:

```
#content{ 
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
```

Comment: Correct, that how it is set-up, so when the page opens it is indeed correct. With what I have problem is the anchor links in the top menu, which link to this same page, that they scroll to the top of their respective div, and thus the menu hides the top part.